# How do I get rid of excess cells in a table in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to recreate our class schedule in html, my problem is everytime i do rowspan in my table it gets excess amount of cells in the right side of the table or colspan the other cells gets messed up or resized. What did I do wrong can someone explain?tyia

[This is what I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrLwX.png)

[Result of my HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZtiF.png)

[Table Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GFUl.png)

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvIq3.png)

I also want the Time column border to get thick like the original table but when I do style it nothing happens.

Comment: Also when I try to put data in other cell it displays data where it's not supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As attached img shows to create such table you will require to use appropriate `rowspan` and `colspan` attribute for `<td>` element.

The output img shows you have used the `rowspan` and `colspan` but forgot to remove the extra `<td>` which left as it is when you use `rowspan` and `colspan` attribute and thus you are getting extra column with rows at the end of table.

See if this snippet helps you:

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size:10px;
}

table th {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

table td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>TIME</th>
      <th>MONDAY</th>
      <th>TUESDAY</th>
      <th>WEDNESDAY</th>
      <th>THURSDAY</th>
      <th>FRIDAY</th>
      <th>SATURDAY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>7.00</td>
      <td>7.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>7.30</td>
      <td>8.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>8.00</td>
      <td>8.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>8.30</td>
      <td>9.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>9.00</td>
      <td>9.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>9.30</td>
      <td>10.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10.00</td>
      <td>10.30</td>

      <td rowspan="6">GNED 02<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Ms. Afiano</td>
      <td rowspan="6">DCIT 21 (LAB)<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Ms. Villavicencio</td>
      <td rowspan="2">DCIT 22 (LAB)<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Mr. Rocillo</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="6">CoSC S0<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Mr. Dula</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10.30</td>
      <td>11.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>11.00</td>
      <td>11.30</td>

      <td rowspan="4">DCIT 21 (LAB)<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Ms. Villavicencio</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>11.30</td>
      <td>12.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>12.00</td>
      <td>12.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>12.30</td>
      <td>1.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1.00</td>
      <td>1.30</td>

      <td rowspan="6">GNED 05<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Dr. Tosco</td>
      <td rowspan="12">DCIT 22 (LAB)<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Mr. Rocillo</td>
      <td rowspan="4">FIIT 1<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Mr. Galang</td>
      <td rowspan="6">GNED 11<br> BSIT 1-4<br> Mr. Verano</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1.30</td>
      <td>2.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2.00</td>
      <td>2.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2.30</td>
      <td>3.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3.00</td>
      <td>3.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3.30</td>
      <td>4.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4.00</td>
      <td>4.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="2">CvSU 101 <br> BSIT 1-4<br>Ms. Busoo</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4.30</td>
      <td>5.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>5.00</td>
      <td>5.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>5.30</td>
      <td>6.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>6.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>6.30</td>
      <td>7.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>7.00</td>
      <td>7.30</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>7.30</td>
      <td>8.00</td>

      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it I have so much to learn!

Comment: So if i'm going to use rowspan i'll have to subtract it to the next cells?

Comment: I want to learn how you do it sir, so if I have 8 <td> tags per row and if I use rowspan="6" the next row would be two <td> tags only?

Comment: Yes. The rowspan attribute specifies the number of rows a cell should span. That is if a row spans two rows, it means it will take up the space of two rows in that table. It allows the single table cell to span the height of more than one cell or row. Thus you will have to remove extra column.

Comment: Please call me Nikhil, I am just a regular guy. You can refer some threads/docs with examples related to HTML 'rowspan' attribute you will get idea.

Comment: Thank you so much Nikhil! looking forward to read those threads and understand more about rowspan and colspan.